# Using Ruby to access LDAP DIT

Tags: ruby, ldap, openldap

We use ACLs to grant access to svn repositories. The users/groups are stored in LDAP (openLDAP 2.4 (LDAP3). Does anyone know or used libraries/package (gems) I can use. Basically, I will traverse LDAP DIT and update my svn file based on that.

1. Connect to ldaps://xxxxxxxxxxx:636
2. Traverse DIT (subtree based on 'ou')
3. Read attributes
4. Write svn ACL file.

That's the high-level overview of what I would need to do. So, my question is regarding ldap package/library that I could use. I have heard of Net::LDAP. I'm very new to Ruby, so, I'm learning it as I go along.

Also, please correct me if I am mistaken. We are using ldaps:// that means when I connect to ldap server, the server will send a certificate. Do I need to do anything special to handle the certificate? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Ruby/LDAP](http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/) before, things worked fine with me.
There is a code example that comes with the gem. Also have a look at the [documentation](http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/rdoc/).

Comment: Thanks... I'll try that out tonight